# Table not sorting correctly as date field is a string, using an over function and need to know to convert Order by to Datetime

Tags: sql-server

I am working with a dashboard software that has limited features, i.e. no way to set the yaxis.  Therefore this has to be worked into the code.  This means the datetime field has to be alphanumeric, due to the yaxis aspect.  However, the table now sorts incorrectly.  So rather than 1, 2, 3 it sorts as 1, 10, 11, 12 .  I've look on here for the answer, but there's nothing that works with an Over function, which is necessary as its for a line graph showing cumulative sales figures over a month.

It is MSSQL that I am using:

```
SELECT DATENAME(day, DATEADD(day,day(oh_datetime),-1)),
SUM(SUM((CASE oh_sot_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 4 THEN -1 WHEN 2 THEN 0 WHEN 3 THEN 0 WHEN 6 THEN 0 WHEN 11 THEN 0 END) * oht_net)) over (ORDER BY day(oh_datetime)) AS 'Orders In($)',
SUM((CASE oh_cd_id WHEN 11728 THEN 1 END) * oht_net) AS 'Target($)'
FROM order_header_total 
JOIN order_header ON oht_oh_id = oh_id
WHERE year(oh_datetime) = year(GETDATE()) AND month(oh_datetime) = month(GETDATE())
GROUP BY day(oh_datetime)
UNION SELECT 'YAxis','0','0'
```

Comment: You have tagged MySql, not SQL Server; tagging the correct database is important if you are going to attract people who can potentially help. Your question needs clarity with sample data and desired results. Please read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *" So rather than 1, 2, 3 it sorts as 1, 10, 11, 12"* this suggests that your columns are a string based data type, not a numerical one. `'2'` is **greater than** `'10'` in strings.

Comment: Side note, that `WHERE` isn't SARGable; don't use functions on your columns in the `WHERE`. Here you should be using date boundaries with `>=` and `<`.

Comment: Thanks.  The column is string, but needs to be to work with the yaxis element.   I need the figures to display as string but sort as dates.  And on the WHERE, these dates need to be set as current month, as the plan is this graph updates without ever needing to be amended.  I would have thought using date boundaries would mean that the dates entered would have to be amended each month.